# Embedding third party JS module into React JS component

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I have a separate (stand-alone) third party module, which uses HTML & Jquery (websocket) and JQXDataGrid. Now, I need to bring this module into React component. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: So how should I include those external javascripts? import statement is giving some issue. Tried these too - "dangerously-set-inner-html" and "react-load-script" but doesn't seem to work.